# Mecanum wheels begin to make robot spin around rather than move to the side

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, mechanisms, battery, electronics

I am using mecanum wheels to steer my robot which I am programming using an arduino. The main problem that I am having is that whenever I attempt to make the robot move sideways like this:

[image]

Instead the robot is doing something along the lines of this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Either way, I was firstly thinking that this problem might have came from weight distribution, so I put the battery pack in the centre of the robot rather than having it at the back. This did nothing.

My next consideration that I am having could be to do with the power sources, I am using 6 1.2V AA batteries (all in series I think, I am not the best when it comes to electrical power, I am on more of the programming side).

What I have are 4 motors, the 2 front motors are connected to the the front motor driver and the 2 back motors are connected to the back motor driver. One incline I have is that the power the 2 motor drivers are getting is not correct in some way.  What I have are 2 wires each for the voltage for the motor driver, both of these wires are connected up to a piece of cabling which allows 2 pins to connect to 1 pin (like an adapter). These 2 pins for the voltage connect to the cable and the other 1 pin on the cable connects up to the 7.2V pin on the arduino pin.

The same type of cabling that I have mentioned above is used for the ground on the arduino as well.

One thing I have observed is that when the motors are moving the LED built into the motor drivers (this goes for both motor drivers) begins to get dimmer. The next idea I had after this was that perhaps one of the rollers present on one of the wheels is quite stiff. The final idea I had and I think might be causing the problem is that one or two wheels are having a large force acting down from the due to them not perhaps working properly.

Comment: I don't know if many of us will know what "mecanum wheels" are. If it's a brand name then it should be capitalised to indicate that. A nice, sharp, cropped photo might help understand your question. And a link to the datasheet for the wheels might be a good idea.

Comment: @Transistor They are just basically omnidirectional wheels. There are tonnes of them out there:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecanum_wheel

Comment: Then you shouldn't have any difficulty finding a good photo to add to your question. The guys who might give a good answer are busy people. Make it easy for them. Also, you need to credit the author of the image you've used. That's SE policy.

Comment: You may have a partial key to your solution with the dimming LEDs, but consider to elevate the vehicle, wheels off the ground and operate the system. You'll see quickly if one or more wheels are not driving in the correct manner. If power is the problem, it must be solved before directional fidelity.

Comment: Are the blue arrows in your diagram accurate to real life? That is, are some of the wheels not spinning when they're supposed to be?

Comment: If power is the problem you can consider running the motors more slowly.

Comment: Can the robot move forward and backward correctly? Any photos/videos of the real unit? There are no 7.2V arduino pins; do not exceed 5 volts. Did you program the unit or did you use someone else's code?

Comment: @ericnutsch All is done by me. Don't worry the arduino VIN pin is the pin I am using not the 5V pin

Comment: Like another user mentioned above: set the unit so the wheels are not touching the ground. Test your code and confirm the functions move the correct respective wheels. If all of that works and you as re still having issues, post back with photos or a video of the issue.

Comment: @ericnutsch One thing I tested out today was that there is a delay with the front motor driver compared to the back motor driver (They both have the same voltage input pin and same GND pin)

Comment: @user253751 changing the power made no difference the same problem occurred when I used different speed